# How can I combine dictionaries with the same keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
dicts = [
    {'key_a': valuex1,
     'key_b': valuex2,
     'key_c': valuex3},

    {'key_a': valuey1,
     'key_b': valuey2,
     'key_c': valuey3},

    {'key_a': valuez1,
     'key_b': valuez2,
     'key_c': valuez3}
]
```

I would like to take these and construct a big dictionary like so:

```
big_dict = {
    'key_a': [valuex1, valuey1, valuez1],
    'key_b': [valuex2, valuey2, valuez2],
    'key_c': [valuex3, valuey3, valuez3]
}
```

Is there any elegant "[zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip)"-like way for me to do this?

All the keys are always going to be identical.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
big_dict = {}
for k in dicts[0]:
    big_dict[k] = [d[k] for d in dicts]
```

Or, with a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{k: [d[k] for d in dicts] for k in dicts[0]}
```

Comment: Just adding a detail to avoid an KeyError when any of the sub-dictionaries doesn't have all keys:

{k: [d[k] for d in results if k in d.keys()] for k in results[0]}

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). The benefit of this solution is it does not require keys to be consistent across dictionaries, and it still maintains the minimum O(*n*) time complexity.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_list = [{'key_a': 'valuex1', 'key_b': 'valuex2', 'key_c': 'valuex3'},
             {'key_a': 'valuey1', 'key_b': 'valuey2', 'key_c': 'valuey3'},
             {'key_a': 'valuez1', 'key_b': 'valuez2', 'key_c': 'valuez3'}]            

d = defaultdict(list)
for myd in dict_list:
    for k, v in myd.items():
        d[k].append(v)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'key_a': ['valuex1', 'valuey1', 'valuez1'],
             'key_b': ['valuex2', 'valuey2', 'valuez2'],
             'key_c': ['valuex3', 'valuey3', 'valuez3']})
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the dicts have the same set of keys, this will work:

```
dict((k, [d[k] for d in dictList]) for k in dictList[0])
```

If they may have different keys, you'll need to first built a set of keys by doing set unions on the keys of the various dicts:

```
allKeys = reduce(operator.or_, (set(d.keys()) for d in dictList), set())
```

Then you'll need to protect against missing keys in some dicts:

```
dict((k, [d[k] for d in [a, b] if k in d]) for k in allKeys)
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension: `{k: [d[k] for d in dictList[ for k in dictList[0]}`

Comment: Yes, if you're using a Python version that supports dictionary comprehensions.  I'm using 2.6 myself so I don't have that.

Comment: a dict comprehension is syntactically synonymous to a generator expression where `{key: value ...}` is replaced with `dict((key, value) ...)`, which is even valid in 2.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library you can use Pandas. The `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a list of dictionaries directly:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(dictList).to_dict(orient='list')

{'key_a': ['valuex1', 'valuey1', 'valuez1'],
 'key_b': ['valuex2', 'valuey2', 'valuez2'],
 'key_c': ['valuex3', 'valuey3', 'valuez3']}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can merge dictionaries in the following way:

```
def merge_dicts(dict_list, separator=''):
    """
    Merges list of dictionaries to a single dictionary, Concatenates values with the same key.
    :param dict_list: list of dictionaries to be merged.
    :param separator: separator to be inserted between values of same key.
    :return: Merged dictionary.
    """
    return {k1: separator.join([d[k1] for d in dict_list if k1 in d])
            for k1 in set(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [k.keys() for k in dict_list]))
    }
```