# How to bind dict together from a list of dicts?

Tags: python

```
x=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':6,'b':5},{'a':3,'b':4}]
y={'a':[1,6,3],'b':[2,5,4]}
```

x is a list of dicts, where all dicts have same keys, now I want to merge the values to a list, as shown in the example, is there a fast implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine dictionaries with the same keys in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533274/how-can-i-combine-dictionaries-with-the-same-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If all dicts in `x` are guaranteed to have the same keys, you can do:

```py
y = {k: [d[k] for d in x] for k in d[0]}
```

If not, you'll have to find the union of those first,

```py
keys = {k for d in x for k in d.keys()}
```

Then iterate over that instead.

```py
y = {k: [d[k] for d in x if k in d] for k in keys}
```

---

More verbose, you could write:

```py
y = dict()
for d in x:
    for k, v in d.items():
        y.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: This implementation seems to contain 2 for loops thus has innecessary accesses.

Comment: The original data structure is nested, so of course it takes nested loops to iterate over it. None of the accesses it does are unnecessary.

Comment: @Linghao.Chen you'll find that you need one `for` to obtain your list of possible keys, and another to find the values therein

Comment: @kaya3 whoops typo (obviously :D). Thanks

Comment: ...or just `d` (because you are iterating over the keys anyway).

Comment: @Austin yeah but `d.keys()` is more explicit and no less performant. Plus the alternative is `k for d in x for k in d` which makes me want to cry. Too many single-letter var names